# How does a group 15 oxide react with water?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Given the following reactants:

> $\ce{P2O5}$ and $\ce{H2O}$

How does one determine what product the two will form in a reaction?

I instantly tried to treat the problem as a double displacement reaction. However, the compounds that I got by doing so were absurd. Do double replacement reactions only occur with ionic compounds (e.g., the cations of two ions switch)?

The two elements listed above form $\ce{H3PO4}$. How do I even go about determining that? What indicates that such a product forms from those two reactants?

Comment: Hint: try an addition reaction instead of double replacement.

Answer (score 1):

The reaction between the two substance you have mentioned above in synthesis 
it is an acid-base reaction .
and about the other question you asked above i can say that we have reactions where two ionic substances take part in oxidation reduction reactions instead of double replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Let me outline the answer previously given by *eyesun*:

In order to figure out how something might react with water, it is helpful to describe and categorize the starting material and to find analogies.

1. Apparently, $\ce{P2O5}$ is a group 15 oxide, the oxide of a non-metal.
2. Other non-metal oxides that come to our mind are from the same element ($\ce{P2O3}$), from the same group ($\ce{N2O5}$), or from the neighboring group 14 ($\ce{CO2}$) and group 16 ($\ce{SO2}$, $\ce{SO3}$, $\ce{SeO2}$).

What other compounds do we know that are similar to these oxides?

3. We do know that a number of **oxo acids** exist. Mostly, they do contain one atom of a group 14-16 element with a couple of oxygen atoms and some protons attached.
4. Can we match these?

   $$\ce{H2SO3 <=> SO2 + H2O}$$
   $$\ce{H2SO4 <=> SO3 + H2O}$$
   $$\ce{H2CO3 <=> CO2 + H2O}$$
   $$\ce{2HNO3 <=> N2O5 + 2H2O}$$

We conclude that these non-metal oxides are like **oxo acid minus water** and we therefore decide to call them **anhydrides**.

5. Having worked our way through all of these, we decide to apply our knowledge to $\ce{P2O5}$:

   $$\ce{2 H3PO4 <=> P2O5 + 2 H2O}$$

to realize that phosphorous pentoxide is the anhydride of orthophosphoric acid.

Comment: I would add that the complete name of this acid is the orthophosphoric acid. \ce{H3PO4}.

Comment: @Another.Chemist Good point. Fixed.